# Why is Mongo string comparison reading equivalent strings as inequivalent? pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, string-comparison

Using pymongo, I'm searching for MongoDB documents in which the string value in one field is not equivalent to the string value in another field. I've tried $cmp, $strcasecmp, $ne, and $eq, but they all keep returning that strings that look equivalent to me are not equivalent.

The pipeline starts as a join between collections with documents like the following examples:

```
# test collection:
[
 {'_id': '611868136', 'doc_type': 'way'},
 {'_id': '5792648632', 'doc_type': 'node'},
 {'_id': '611868133', 'doc_type': 'node'},
 {'_id': '1', 'doc_type': 'node'}
]

# refer_docs collection:
[
 {'_id': '8483444',
  'refs': [{'ref': '611868136', 'ref_type': 'way'},
           {'ref': '5792648632', 'ref_type': 'node'},
           {'ref': '611868133', 'ref_type': 'way'}],
  'doc_type': 'relation'}
]
```

Now, here's the aggregation:

```
import pymongo
mongo_client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
osm_db = mongo_client.osm
refer_docs_col = osm_db["refer_docs"]

pipeline = [
    { "$unwind" : "$refs" },
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "test",
            "localField" : "refs.ref",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "ref_doc"
        }
    },
    { "$match" : { "ref_doc" : { "$ne" : [] } } },
    { "$unwind" : "$ref_doc"},
    { "$match" : { "refs.ref_type" : { "$ne" : "$ref_doc.doc_type" } } },
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 1, "refs" : 1, "ref_doc.doc_type" : 1, 
                     "cmp" : { "$cmp" : [ "refs.ref_type",
                                          "ref_doc.doc_type" ] } } },
    { "$limit" : 1 }
]
[doc for doc in refer_docs_col.aggregate(pipeline)]
```

I would expect the following document to be returned:

```
[{'_id': '467676638',
 'refs': {'ref': '611868133', 'ref_type': 'way'},
 'ref_doc': {'doc_type': 'node'},
 'cmp': 1}]
```

But, it also returns documents that look like this:

```
[{'_id': '8483444',
  'refs': {'ref': '611868136', 'ref_type': 'way'},
  'ref_doc': {'doc_type': 'way'},
  'cmp': 1},
 {'_id': '8483444',
  'refs': {'ref': '5792648632', 'ref_type': 'node'},
  'ref_doc': {'doc_type': 'node'},
  'cmp': 1},
 {'_id': '8483444',
  'refs': {'ref': '611868133', 'ref_type': 'way'},
  'ref_doc': {'doc_type': 'node'},
  'cmp': 1}]
```

Notice the compared fields ("refs.ref_type", "ref_doc.doc_type") clearly contain equivalent values in two cases(e.g. "node"), but the comparison operator returns 1 in all cases, indicating the first value is greater than the second. It should return 0, indicating the two values are equivalent.

Ack! Why??

Comment: Rewrite the example using only mongo shell syntax without pymongo and change the sample data to be complete and valid mongo shell syntax.

Comment: @D.SM Why rewrite without pymongo?

Comment: If you want the widest audience to consider your question, make it accessible to that audience. Every mongodb developer has the mongo shell installed, only some have pymongo.

Comment: @D.SM Ah, that makes sense. My objective is to make it work in PyMongo. Perhaps someone will offer a solution in Mongo, and it will be up to me to translate to PyMongo. Or, perhaps the problem is the way PyMongo behaves. I will go ahead and try it in Mongo to test that possiblility. I'm guessing someone who can provide the answer can spot the problem pretty easily. Maybe not.

Comment: @D.SM Translating to Mongo was a useful exercise, haha. I found the error. I forgot a couple of dollar signs so I was comparing the literal strings of the field names rather than the field values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot a couple of dollar signs in the $cmp statement, so I was comparing the literal strings of the field names rather than the field values. So obvious, ugh.

```
pipeline = [
    { "$unwind" : "$refs" },
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "test",
            "localField" : "refs.ref",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "ref_doc"
        }
    },
    { "$match" : { "ref_doc" : { "$ne" : [] } } },
    { "$unwind" : "$ref_doc"},
#     { "$match" : { "refs.ref_type" : { "$ne" : "$ref_doc.doc_type" } } },
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 1, "refs" : 1, "ref_doc.doc_type" : 1, 
                     "cmp" : { "$cmp" : [ "$refs.ref_type",
                                          "$ref_doc.doc_type" ] } } },
    { "$match" : { "cmp" : { "$ne" : 0 } } }
]
[doc for doc in refer_docs_col.aggregate(pipeline)]
```